# How to fork a project in Github again?

Tags: git, github

I forked the project https://github.com/android/camera-samples a month ago, the forked project is listed as myname/camera in my repo.

Today I find that https://github.com/android/camera-samples has been updated, I fork the project again.

In my mind, the old myname/camera in my repo will be update, but in fact no action im my  myname/camera.

Do I must delete  myname/camera in my repo first, then fork https://github.com/android/camera-samples for the latest edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `sync` your fork. The best thing would be to familiarize yourself with the concept of [**remotes**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

See all of your `remotes` via command line:

```sh
git remote -v
```

#### Before your update (your remotes look like this)

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/HelloCW/camera-samples (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/HelloCW/camera-samples (push)
```

#### After your update (your remote changed)

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/HelloCW/camera-samples (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/HelloCW/camera-samples (push)
upstream        https://github.com/android/camera-samples (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/android/camera-samples (push)
```

You need to `add` a remote and `pull` from the upstream repository and push the updates to your fork.

```
upstream  -->  local clone --> your fork
```

Follow these steps:

#### 1. Clone your fork (to your local machine):

```
git clone git@github.com:YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-FORKED-REPO.git
```

#### 2. Add remote from original repository (upstream) in your forked repository:

```
cd into/cloned/fork-repo
git remote add upstream git://github.com/ORIGINAL-DEV-USERNAME/REPO-YOU-FORKED-FROM.git
git fetch upstream
```

#### 3. Updating your fork from original repo to keep up with their changes:

```
git pull upstream master
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/CristinaSolana/1885435

Comment: Thanks! but I think that your way is a little complex. Can I delete my fork first, then refork again for the latest edition?

Comment: This is the the standard way. You can not delete your fork if e.g. you have a branch you are working on. If you are not working on your fork. Why would you even fork it in the first place?
It is easier than it looks. You need to setup your remotes only one time. After that you only need to update your local copy and push to your fork on github. This are only two steps.

Answer (score 1):

[Github page snapshot showing how to fetch updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfjGs.png)

No need to delete the forked repo and fork again.

Did you notice the pop-up stating `fetch upstream` on your forked-repo?

Click that button, then see the dropdown to `fetch and merge`

Click *that* and the `updated-forked-repo` becomes available without deleting the `original forked repo`.

Have a look at the image and it might help you find the option.